# Insert pseudocode into Word through Aurora and mikTex

Tags: miktex, pseudocode

Using Microsoft Word 2013, Windows 10

Here is my code:

```
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{2}
\begin{algorithm}[H] 
\caption{*******************************************} 
\label{ABCLFRS}
\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\Require{S,$\lambda$,T,k} 
\Ensure{$\mathbf{w}_{222}$}\\ 
\textbf{initialize}: Set $\mathbf{w}_1 = 0$ 
\For{$t = 1,2,...,T$} 
\State Choose $A_t \subset[m]$
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Here is my Aurora Setting:
[image: my Aurora Setting]

Here is what appeared in my word:
[image]

There are two questions:

1. Why the line number is zero for each line?
2. Why there is `=0` an the end of the algorithm?

Comment: You should also add a **compilable** MWE in the question.